# Error: No Such Version of Amazon EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to Add an Ingress rule to one of my security groups.
All I'm trying to do is add my Ip-address `192.88.137.28` to my EC2 security group `sg-fakegrpid`.

```
User Type: IAM
region: eu-west-1
```

So, should I make the endpoint as `ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/` instead of `ec2.amazonaws.com/`?

This is a signed request & encoded as well.

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=THISISFAKEAWSDRACULA
&Action=AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress
&GroupId=sg-fakegrpid
&IpPermissions.1.FromPort=3389
&IpPermissions.1.IpProtocol=tcp
&IpPermissions.1.IpRanges.1.CidrIp=192.88.137.28%2F32
&IpPermissions.1.ToPort=3389
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2014-06-09T10%3A57%3A31Z
&Signature=hIKzcwPDdYKw4HsxozCFzzzzl8LxzsdC6XlX83DV4NU=
```

I use the Java SDK to create the signature. Here's the link to it.

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html
```

When I run the above given url in the browser, I get the following response.

> The requested version (2005-10-05) of service AmazonEC2 does not exist

Then I visited this page `http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html`

I generated a signed url from there. But signature is different from the above url's signature.

```
http://ec2.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=THISISFAKEAWSDRACULA
&Action=AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress
&GroupId=sg-fakegrpid
&IpPermissions.1.FromPort=3389
&IpPermissions.1.IpProtocol=tcp
&IpPermissions.1.IpRanges.1.CidrIp=192.88.137.28%2F32
&IpPermissions.1.ToPort=3389
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2014-06-09T11%3A22%3A14.000Z
&Signature=hr%2FwZBMi3duJpOgud6Hzx2MIhd8QUuqzockqyysRQCY%3D
```

But I get the same error as before.

This is the string to sign:

```
GET
ec2.amazonaws.com
AWSAccessKeyId=THISISFAKEAWSDRACULA
&Action=AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress
&GroupId=sg-fakegrpid
&IpPermissions.1.FromPort=3389
&IpPermissions.1.IpProtocol=tcp
&IpPermissions.1.IpRanges.1.CidrIp=192.88.137.28%2F32
&IpPermissions.1.ToPort=3389
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2014-06-09T11%3A22%3A14.000Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this '&Version=2014-05-01' and everything worked fine.

This parameter is used to specify the version of the service we are trying to use. This is the latest version of EC2.

When I don't mention a specific version, aws looks for this version (2005-10-05) of service & may be, it does not exist.